# Using a variable instead where R.drawable

Tags: java, android

I have a notifications in my application.
However on different event I muse show different icon in the notification bar.
And I`m just wondering how syntactically to write this.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.card_red)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker(message)
                .setContentTitle("Real Madrid 2:1 Barcelona")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();
```

I have a variable which is holding the event type - 
event = 5;
if(event == 5) icon = card_red;
And I must put that icon variable into the notification creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with a simple switch case here? `switch` on the event type variable, and return the corresponding `drawable` ID. Then pass that ID into `setSmallIcon`.

```
int drawable = -1;
switch(eventType) {
  case 5 : drawable = R.drawable.card_red; break;
  case 6 : drawable = R.drawable.card_blue; break;
  //Other cases as appropriate
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I`m just pretty new in the java world.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int[] icons = new int[] {R.drawable.card_red,  R.drawable.card_blue,  R.drawable.card_black};
```

You should be mapping the icon's index in array correctly.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(icons[event])
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker(message)
                .setContentTitle("Real Madrid 2:1 Barcelona")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int drawableId = -1
switch(eventId) {
 case EVENT0:
    drawableId = R.drawable.event0;
    break;
 case EVENT1:
    drawableId = R.drawable.event1;
    break;
 case EVENT2:
    drawableId = R.drawable.event2;
    break;
}
if (drawableId != -1) {
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(drawableId)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker(message)
                .setContentTitle("Real Madrid 2:1 Barcelona")
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification(); 
}
```